# Fastest ways to check if a value already exists in a stl container

Tags: c++, c++11

I am holding a very big list of memory addresses (around `400.000`) and need to check if a certain address already exists in it 400.000 times a second.

A code example to illustrate my setup:

```
std::set<uintptr_t> existingAddresses; // this one contains 400.000 entries

while (true) {
    // a new list with possible new addresses
    std::set<uintptr_t> newAddresses; // also contains about ~400.000 entries

    // in my own code, these represent a new address list
    for (auto newAddress : newAddresses) {

        // already processed this address, skip it
        if (existingAddresses.find(newAddress) != existingAddresses.end()) {
          continue;
        }

        // we didn't have this address yet, so process it.
        SomeHeavyTask(newAddress);

        // so we don't process it again
        existingAddresses.emplace(newAddress);
    }

    Sleep(1000);
}
```

This is the first implementation I came up with and I think it can be greatly improved.

Next I came up with using some custom indexing strategy, also used in databases. The idea is to take a part of the value and use that to index it in its own group set. If I would take for example the last two numbers of the address I would have `16^2 = 256` groups to put addresses in.

So I would end up with a map like this:

```
[FF] -> all address ending with `FF`
[EF] -> all addresses ending with `EF`
[00] -> all addresses ending with `00`
// etc...
```

With this I will only need to do a lookup on ~`360` entries in the corresponding set. Resulting in ~`360` lookups being done 400.000 times a second. Much better!

I am wondering if there are any other tricks or better ways to do this? My goal is to make this address lookup as FAST as possible.

Comment: maybe [unordered_set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) could do the job for you?

Comment: @slawekwin This is definitly not faster than doing index based lookup. Also I think it will be even slower than `set` since a `set` is ordered so it can already skip 50% of the values, which will result in a faster lookup.

Comment: @SteffenBrem: `std::unordered_set` is hash based, so it (theoretically) has ~`O(1)` lookup, which scales better than the `O(log n)` lookup of `set`. In practice, it's going to have a small increase in overhead relative to the true `O(1)` indexing of, say, `std::vector`, but it should be pretty close to `O(1)`.

Comment: Addresses are very unlikely to be randomly scattered in memory.  In particular, it is very likely that addresses are aligned on a 16-bit word boundary (reducing your effective size to 128 entries), and pretty likely that they will be aligned on an 8-byte or even 16-byte boundary (which would reduce your entries to only 16 - not 256).

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the many responses! So basically an `unordered_set` is already doing efficient indexing based on calculated hash of the value? So it is already doing waaay less lookups, not 400.000 lookups to check for a single entry.

Comment: Even if you stick with `std::set` it has a `find` method: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find which will use the order in the set to give logarithmic lookup - so should be quicker than your loop which might trawl through (almost) everything in the set.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`std::set<uintptr_t>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) uses a balanced tree, so look-up time is `O(log N)`.

[`std::unordered_set<uintptr_t>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set), on the other hand, is hash-based, with lookup time of `O(1)`.

Although this is only an `asymptotic complexity` measure, meaning that there is no guaranteed improvement due to constant factors involved, the difference may prove significant when the collection contains 400,000 elements.

Comment: Okay, so as I understand it would not be wise to implement a custom indexing strategy for this but just go with an `unordered_set`. One question though. Would using `find` be the fastest way to do the lookup on the unordered set?

Comment: @SteffenBrem Yes, `existingAddresses.find(newAddress) != existingAddresses.end()` check is the fastest way to do the look-up. Overall, `std::unordered_set` should be a drop-in replacement for `std::set` in the program from your post.

Comment: @SteffenBrem Its not hard to beat the stl unordered_set implementations with your own hash set implementation in orders of magnitude. The stl version is incredibly general whereas you have the advantage of knowing your data which allows you to cut more corners and optimize further.

Answer (score 1):

You may use algorithm similar to merge:

```
std::set<uintptr_t> existingAddresses; // this one contains 400.000 entries

while (true) {
    // a new list with possible new addresses
    std::set<uintptr_t> newAddresses; // also contains about ~400.000 entries
    auto existing_it = existingAddresses.begin();
    auto new_it = newAddresses.begin();

    while (new_it != newAddresses.end() && existing_it != existingAddresses.end()) {
        if (*new_it < *existing_it) {
            // we didn't have this address yet, so process it.
            SomeHeavyTask(*new_it);
            // so we don't process it again
            existingAddresses.insert(existing_it, *new_it);
            ++new_it;
        } else if (*existing_it < *new_it) {
            ++existing_it;
        } else { // Both equal
            ++existing_it;
            ++new_it;
        }
    }
    for (new_it != newAddresses.end())
        // we didn't have this address yet, so process it.
        SomeHeavyTask(*new_it);
        // so we don't process it again
        existingAddresses.insert(existingAddresses.end(), *new_it);
        ++new_it;
    }
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

Complexity is now linear: `O(N + M)` instead of `O(N log M)` (with `N` number of new addresses, and `M` count for old ones).

Comment: If both sets are ordered you merge algorithm is the fastest way because you already use the sorted structure of the data.